# How to structure a like query in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a simple application where posts appear on a user's home page and he can like or unlike them.
first when there were no users in the applications, I made a simple boolean field "liked", as shown in the figure, to determine if a post is liked or un-liked. However, when I started working with users, I find it hard to find the perfect structure for the likes field.

In Firestore, I added a field named "likedBy" for each post, which contains a map with a key of each user's id and a boolean to determine if the user liked the post or not.

[image]

I don't know if this structure is suitable or not, and if not, is there a better way to reach my goal?

Comment: Problem with above structure. It's ok till there is less registered users.

Answer (score 1):

The `likedBy` field is enough to cover most use cases.
Just store in `likedBy` an array of all users who liked the post by user ID. When a user likes - add the user ID to the array and remove it upon unlike.
That means you can also remove the `likes` and `liked` field as you can get it from reading the `likedBy` array.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going one step further and save more than the User ID. You could also save the User `displayName` and `photoUrl`. That way, you don't need to read ($$$$money$$$$) the documents of every `Users` who liked `Posts` in order to display their name and/or avatar.

Comment: While I like storing the additional data like `displayName` and `photoUrl` this is going to lead to problems when the commenting user updates their information since you would either need to go through _every_ post and update that information if it is there (-> lots of writes) or accept that information will be wrong.